# Why does the lambdify function from sympy throw an error in my case?

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy, newtons-method, lambdify

The error lies with the lambdify function. It says syntax error for some reason. 
This is what is says exactly:

> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\lambdify.py", line 434, in lambdify func = eval(lstr, namespace).

The program crashes right after the user enters the tolerance. This is a Newtons Method program (or at least my attempt at one). Any suggestions on how to improve this code in general would be greatly appreciated too.

What I enter for `f` and `dfdx` is the following:

```
x**3 + 3*x + 5
```

and

```
3*x**2 + 3
```

respectively. As for `v0` and `eps`, I enter `1` and `0.000001` respectively. The program terminates with the aforementioned error no matter what I enter (assuming it uses x as the variable, otherwise it says undefined and that's it).

```
import sympy
import sys

v0 = int(input("Please enter the v0 value: "))

eps = float(input("Please enter the tolerance: "))

f = lambda x : eval('input("Enter the function: ")')

dfdx = lambda x : eval('input("Enter the derivative: ")')

x=sympy.symbols('x')

func = sympy.lambdify(f,x)

deriv = sympy.lambdify(f,x)

def Newton(func, deriv, v0, eps):
    f_value = func(v0)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            v0 = v0 - float(f_value)/deriv(v0)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", v0)
            sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error

        f_value = func(v0)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return v0, iteration_counter

Newton(func,deriv,v0,eps)
```

Comment: I don't think those `eval()` calls are doing what you think they are doing.  Try them in the REPL.

Comment: There is no [mcve] here. We don't know what was entered in response to all those input prompts.

Comment: @Victor Reaver you might be interested in ongoing work which would allow SymPy to generate code for Newton's method directly from a symbolic expression: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/13100/files#diff-3a6d66b018fe657a69245850eb8f2a1aR11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU your cunning plan is to first use Python interpreter to build a function from user's string (using `input`) and then to use SymPy to build a re-usable function from that. There are a few problems with your code, the most important probably is that you get signature of SymPy methods wrong.

Also idea of providing `dfdx` as input doesn't look good to me. If the original function `f` has a good derivative that you can calculate, SymPy can probably calculate it on its own.

So if you fix some obvious mistakes, you may get a code like this:

**Python 3.x**

```
import sympy
import sys

v0 = int(input("Please enter the v0 value: "))
eps = float(input("Please enter the tolerance: "))
f_inp = lambda x: eval(input("Enter the function: "))
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f_symb = f_inp(x)
func = sympy.lambdify(x, f_symb)
deriv = sympy.lambdify(x, sympy.diff(f_symb, x))

def Newton(func, deriv, v0, eps):
    f_value = func(v0)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            v0 = v0 - float(f_value) / deriv(v0)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", v0)
            sys.exit(1)  # Abort with error

        f_value = func(v0)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return v0, iteration_counter

print (Newton(func, deriv, v0, eps))
```

**Python 2.x**

```
import sympy
import sys

v0 = int(input("Please enter the v0 value: "))
eps = float(input("Please enter the tolerance: "))
f_inp = lambda x: input("Enter the function: ")
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f_symb = f_inp(x)
func = sympy.lambdify(x, f_symb)
deriv = sympy.lambdify(x, sympy.diff(f_symb, x))

def Newton(func, deriv, v0, eps):
    f_value = func(v0)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            v0 = v0 - float(f_value) / deriv(v0)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", v0)
            sys.exit(1)  # Abort with error

        f_value = func(v0)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return v0, iteration_counter

print Newton(func, deriv, v0, eps)
```

which for your input

```
1
0.000001
x**3 + 3*x + 5
```

produces following output:

> (-1.154171557329764, 5)

The main difference between 2.x and 3.x versions is that [`input` in 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) calls `eval` inside while [`input` in 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) doesn't.

Comment: It says name 'x' is not defined. I am not sure why. It throws that error after I enter the function for f_inp. I would be grateful for a hint. Thank you for fixing the initial code though.

Comment: Never mind actually, I fixed it. Had to swap places between x=sympy.symbols('x') and f_inp and add an eval for the f_inp. Once again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @VictorReaver, sorry. I missed that you used Python 3.x and so `input` doesn't do `eval` automatically. I edited my answer to present both 2.x and 3.x versions.